# Storage manager (SM) Partitioned Micro sd card but how to mount the extended partition and use it as internal storage.?

Tags: adb, storage, shell, adoptable-storage, link2sd

**Question:- Storage manager (SM) Partitioned  Micro sd card but how to mount the extended partition and use it as internal storage.?**

I purchased 6 months before, Samsung Galaxy s20 Fe with android 12 with 128 GB internal memory and a 128 GB external Micro SD card. I am an IT freelancer professional, so I have a job is for testing daily 1000's of different android apps some I have keep installed to create logged reports either monthly weekly or quarterly and my other work is to do some short video advertisements or photo editing and some other GPS technical official apps to do my job in an instant go while traveling.

I want to set default installation of apps location to micro sd card, i tried but it only moves the main APK files, leaving ODBB file like  data, cache, lib, and dex in internal memory thus occupying space in internal memory. I want to keep my internal memory free for output files of video editing to fast rendering of photo editing or video editing file on mobile.

I have tried Adoptable storage ( formatting external micro sd card as internal)  without rooting once in my android 6.0 Marshemellow and thought it may work in android 12.0.

i tried following commands in following sequence

```
adb devices
adb shell

r8q:/ $ sm list-disks adoptable
   Disk: 179,0 (output of list-disk adoptable command)
r8q:/ $ sm has-adoptable
      false
r8q:/ $ sm partition disk:179:0 mixed 40
r8q:/ $ sm set-force-adoptable true
r8q:/ $ sm list-volumes all
        private mounted null
        public:179,1 mounted 5C8A-85AC
        private:179,3 unmountable
        emulated;0 mounted null
r8q:/ $sm format private:179,3
r8q:/ $sm mount private:179,3
r8q:/ $ sm has-adoptable
      false
r8q:/ $ sm list-volumes all
        private mounted null
        public:179,1 mounted 5C8A-85AC
        private:179,3 unmountable
        emulated;0 mounted null
r8q:/ $ ls -al /dev/block/platform/soc/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   80 2022-11-07 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   60 2019-02-11 06:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 1680 2019-02-11 06:25 1d84000.ufshc
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  140 2022-11-07 13:12 8804000.sdhci
r8q:/ $ ls -al /dev/block/platform/soc/8804000.sdhci
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 140 2022-11-07 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  80 2022-11-07 13:12 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 2022-11-07 13:12 by-name
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0p1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0p2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0p3 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
r8q:/ $ ls -al /dev/block/platform/soc/8804000.sdhci/by-name/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 2022-11-07 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 140 2022-11-07 13:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 android_expand -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 android_meta -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 shared -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
```

Result is fine with no errors, it partitioned the micro sd card and converted formatted and mounted my 128GB card to 2 parts ie.as in mobile phone settings>storage in android 12.0 its showing 47.63GB card after commands it means its mounted and the micro external card is parted 47.63 portable is showing. but second  partition is not showing in android and the  files apps moved is still saving in 47.63 gb public:179,1 mounted 5C8A-85AC not the other one which  is private:179,3 unmountable and not being used and remaining 80.37 GB is unallocated and not usable

[image: screenshot of storage]
I rebooted my  android phone twice still.

But internal its still showing 100GB remaining and its not added and why the remaining space partition of  80.37GB  is its not showing in android device how to mount or show in GUI of android and how to now 80.37GB partition as adoptable storage or format remaining  80.37GB as internal memory and extend my internal memory storage and how to use the partition in micro sd card and remaining

i tried $sm mount private:179,3 to  to mount 179,3 private  sd card second parition but still its hidden and showing invisible

on  command  ls -al /dev/block/platform/soc/8804000.sdhci/by-name/

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  18 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0p1 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0p2 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  20 2022-11-07 13:12 mmcblk0p3 -> /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
```

it showed 3 partitions of  micro sd card  ie /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 & p2 & p3  but  how can we mount  the  undisplayed parition by
mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p3 /data/sdext2 will it  write in init.c  so that  its gets  every time i reboot restart  the  android phone. by which command i can show  the  micro sd card hidden partition so that  it can be  displayed in settings-storage and wordk as  adoptable internal storage

Thanks for giving time and reading my question and  i will be  obliged to get experts advice solution for  my problem . Thanks a lot in advance for  your precisous time advice and knowledge sharing and help.